# Handling Windows Cryptographic Services (cryptsvc) dependency

Tags: c++, windows, windows-services

I have a Windows service say `test` which has a dependency on `cryptsvc`. In some systems (like windows XP), `cryptsvc` starts later than my service.

One way to handle this is adding `cryptsvc` as dependent service in my test service.
But this will delay the start of `test` service as well.

I tried manually starting of `cryptsvc` using `startservice()` as part of my service initialization, something like below:

```
SERVICE_STATUS Status;
Status.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_START_PENDING;
setservicestatus(hTestService, &Status);
ServiceInit();
Status.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_RUNNING;
setservicestatus(hTestService, &Status);
```

And

```
ServiceInit()
{
  // launch a worker thread that
  // calls startservice() to start cryptsvc.
}
```

But the call to `startservice()` seems to block for some time and eventually ends with 1056 error (There is already an instance running).

How can I ensure crypt service starts as early as possible, or how can I start crypt service as part of my service initialization. Note that I don't want to strictly ensure that crypt service comes up before my service gets up, but crypt service should be up as soon as possible.

Comment: IIRC you can solve service dependencies in the Service Configuration from the System Configuration. I only have a German System, thus screenshots won't be very helpful, sorry. You may get better results about your question at [SE Superuser](https://superuser.com/) probably.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i have tried using dependency, but that delays start of my test service itself. i would rather like to make cryptsvc start early rather than delaying my service.